# EXCEL: Solver constraints

Tags: excel, constraints, solver

I would like to ask assistance on setting up the solver.

Assuming I have 5 cells that must be allocated value that sum up to 1000. However, some of them can be zero if that will accommodate other constraints. At this point I get some solver outputs that make 4 of the 5 zero, and allocates 1000 to the 1 cell.

I would like to know how do I add another constraints that tells the solver that, say at least 3 of the 5 cannot be zero (any 5).

Your assistance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the constraints such as the sum of these 3 cells has to be greater than x or each of these cells has to be greater or equal to y.

So, if cells b1 to b5 have the results you are looking for then in cells c1 to c5 can be set to 10, 20, 30 or whatever and then in the solver you have:

```
$B$1:$B$5 >= $C$1:$C$5
```

Comment: Thank you Solar Mike. I just need more clarification. At the moment when I run the solver it could result in, e.g., 1) Cell 1 = 200, Cell 2 = 200, Cell 3 = 200, Cell 4 = 200, Cell 5 = 200, or 2) Cell 1 = 500, Cell 2 = 200, Cell 3 = 300, Cell 4 = 0, Cell 5 = 0, or 3) Cell 1 = 1000, Cell 2 = 0, Cell 3 = 0, Cell 4 = 0, Cell 5 = 0. However, I want to put a constraints in that will ensure that at least 3 of these cells (it can be any three, but must be 3 of them) cannot be zero. Could you elaborate if you suggestion will allow this. Thanks again. Really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: So set c1 to c5 to 1 then they cannot be zero, or you can separate  them to individualconstraints, ie b1 >= c1 etc

Comment: I don't think I am explaining this well. I do not want to specify that they cannot be zero, as the solver could find that they must be zero to satisfy constraint. However, I do not want all but 1 to be zero. So I want additional constraints that forces the solver to find alternative values for cells 1 - 5 where more than 1 cell gets allocated its portion of the 1000 (vs giving it to only one of the 5 cells). And the description for cells 1 - 5 changes constantly, so I cannot say cells 3 - 5 cannot be zero. This needs to be dynamic.

Comment: So if you want to avoid zero in any case then set b1 <> 0 and do the same for the others... You can set as many, or few, constraints as you wish